# Django 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ stopped working

Tags: python, django, url, http-status-code-404, admin

Not sure what I've done to break the admin site, but going to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ is not working and gives me the error in the screenshot below:

[image]

Here's the two urls.py files:

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import product_app.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(product_app.urls)),
]
```

and the product_app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from . import views
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^subscribe/$', views.subscribe, name='subscribe'),
    url(r'^products/$', views.products, name = 'products'),
    url(r'^product/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'post_url/', views.post_product, name='post_product'),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='Login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='Logout'),
    url(r'^like_product/$', views.like_product, name='like_product' ),

    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='product-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^product/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

...and just in case, the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['product_images', str(instance.name), filename])


class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images', blank=True, null=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', kwargs={})
```

...finally, my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from .models import Product #, HashTag
from .forms import ProductForm, LoginForm, ContactForm, SubscribeForm, EditProfileForm
from django.views import generic

# edit / delete views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView

# contact and subscribe forms
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from . import forms
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class HomePage(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context=super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = ContactForm
        return context


def products(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username',None)
    user = None
    if username:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            pass
    if user:
        return Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()
    form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'products.html', {'products': products, 'form':form})


class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    paginate_by = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.request.GET.get('username',None)
        user = None
        if username:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
                pass
        if user:
            return Product.objects.filter(user=user)
        return Product.objects.none()


def post_product(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ProductForm(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            product = form.save(commit = False)
            product.user = request.user
            product.likes = 0
            product.save()
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products')

def detail(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    #hashtags = HashTag.objects.filter(product=product_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'product': product})

def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not request.user == user:
        return render(request, 'no.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})

def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)


def like_product(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id', None)

    likes = 0
    if (product_id):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
        if product is not None:
            likes = product.likes + 1
            product.likes = likes
            product.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                # the password verified for the user
                if user.is_active:
                    print("User is valid, active and authenticated")
                    login(request, user)
                    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
                    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
                else:
                    print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
            else:
                # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
                print("The username and password were incorrect.")

    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Product
   form_class = ProductForm
   template_name = 'edit_product.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      # Any manual settings go here
      self.object.save()
      # return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
      return redirect ('products')

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = Product
   template_name = 'product_confirm_delete.html'

   def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse ('products')

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

User = get_user_model()

def subscribe(request):
    form_class = SubscribeForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact/subscribe_template.txt')
            context = dict({'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email,})

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New subscribe form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['steve@steve-shead.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'contact/thank_you_subscribe.html')

    return render(request, 'contact/subscribe.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })

def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact/contact_template.txt')
            context = dict({'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'form_content': form_content,})

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['steve@steve-shead.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'contact/thank_you.html')

    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

I have no clue what I changed to make the admin site not work - any help gratefully received!

Comment: What is `ROOT_URLCONF` set to in your settings file?

Comment: You need to make the default URL configuration file `myproject.urls` and not `product_app.urls`

Comment: @solarissmoke - ugh - ROOT_URLCONF was wrong - probably the only darn setting I didn't check.  Thank you!  If you make this the solution I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `ROOT_URLCONF` setting - it needs to be set to `myproject.urls` but looks like it is currently set to `product_app.urls`.